# Issues in merging the JSON payloads in Dataweave

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I have a below JSON array response from a foreach component added in a list variable:

```html
[{
  "DocumentName": "Test1",
  "renditions": [
    {
      "rendition": "indexData"
    },
    {
      "rendition": "48x48_GIF"
    },
    {
      "rendition": "80x80_JPG"
    },
    {
      "rendition": "100x100_JPG"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "DocumentName": "Test23",
  "renditions": [
    {
      "rendition": "indexData"
    },
    {
      "rendition": "Preview"
    },
    {
      "rendition": "Native File"
    }
  ]
}]
```

And i have a another service which is sending me the JSON response as below:

```html
{
  "results": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "ImageID": "2",
      "Name": "Test1",
      "Owner": "sysadmin",
      "Author": "sysadmin",
      "Creator": "sysadmin"
 },
 {
      "ID": "2",
      "ImageID": "23",
      "Name": "Test23",
      "Owner": "sysadmin",
      "Author": "sysadmin",
      "Creator": "sysadmin"
 }
  ]
}
```

what i want is to combine both the above payloads on the basis of the condition and map the object only if the Name field from the second JSON response matches with the DocumentName of the first JSON response and need to filter out the indexData rendition from the final response and the final response must be as below:

```html
{
  "results": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "ImageID": "2",
      "Name": "Test1",
      "Owner": "sysadmin",
      "Author": "sysadmin",
      "Creator": "sysadmin"
   "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "48x48_GIF",
                    "href": "/abc/48x48_GIF"
                },
    {
                    "rel": "80x80_JPG",
                    "href": "/abc/80x80_JPG"
                },
    {
                    "rel": "100x100_GIF",
                    "href": "/abc/100x100_GIF"
                }
            ]
 },
 {
      "ID": "2",
      "ImageID": "23",
      "Name": "Test23",
      "Owner": "sysadmin",
      "Author": "sysadmin",
      "Creator": "sysadmin"
   "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "Preview",
                    "href": "/abc/Preview"
                },
    {
                    "rel": "Native File",
                    "href": "/abc/Native File"
                }
            ]
 }
  ]
}
```

From the final response indexData must be removed. I tried achieving this with the below dataweave:

```html
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
  "results": (payload.searchResults pluck ({
   "ID": $.xAH_StoreItemNumber,
   "ImageID": $.dID,
   "Name": $.dDocName,
   "Owner": $.dDocOwner,
   "Author": $.dDocAuthor,
   "Creator": $.dDocCreator,
   "links": flowVars.setRenditionsResponse.renditions map ((renditions, indexofRenditions) -> {
   "rel": renditions.rendition
  }) ++ 
      [{
         "rel": "retail-item",
         "href": (p('ah.packshots.api.url') ++ $.xAH_StoreItemNumber)
      }]
  }) when (sizeOf payload) >= 1  otherwise [])
}
```

but its not returning the expected output. Could anyone please help me in the same.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by first flatten the array and then use it as a nested map in the main dataweave !!